# palm api credential error on docker image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, streamlit, google-generativeai, palm-api

Stream lit app using Palm API runs well on local. API key is set on .env file. But docker image shows API credential error while running.

```
API_KEY = os.environ.get('api_key')
import google.generativeai as palm
palm.configure(api_key=API_KEY)
```

[image: Error Log]

Comment: Are you sure your environment variable is called `api_key` and not `API_KEY` for example?

Comment: Depending on your base image, you can try `docker inspect <container_name>' --format "{{.Config.Env}}"` and see if `api_key` is there

Comment: yes resolved the error .thanks for the suggestion